# split data with query in vb6

Tags: sql

```
I have data in my table like this

TrNo | ManRef | Transport
001    ASC1     30000
001    ASC1     15000
002    ASC2     30000
```

and i want the data become like this

```
TrNo | ManRef | Transport 1 | Transport 2
001    ASC1     30000          15000
002    ASC2     30000           -
```

so..any one can help me, how to query this table...pleaseee

Comment: i used like this strSql1 = "select distinct TrNo, ManRef, Transport from mytable

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't need to go Dynamic, a simple conditional aggregation in concert with Row_Number() should do the trick

**Example**

```
Select TrNo
      ,ManRef
      ,sum(case when RN=1 then Transport else 0 end) as Transport1 
      ,sum(case when RN=2 then Transport else 0 end) as Transport2 
      ,sum(case when RN=3 then Transport else 0 end) as Transport3 
      ,sum(case when RN=4 then Transport else 0 end) as Transport4 
      ,sum(case when RN=5 then Transport else 0 end) as Transport5
      ,sum(case when RN=6 then Transport else 0 end) as Transport6
 From (
        Select *
              ,Row_Number() over (Partition By TrNo,ManRef Order By Transport Desc) as RN 
         From YourTable
      ) A
 Group By TrNo,ManRef
```

**Validated Results**

[image]

Comment: @axna2000 it's pretty generic.  What database are you inor what error is being returned

Comment: syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'sum(case RN=1 then transport else 0 end)' i'm used vb6

Comment: @axna2000 vb6 is not a database.  The query is valid.  I validated the results before posting just to make sure I didn't have any typos.

Comment: but jhon the data not just 2 row but more row so how to create the query like this

Comment: @axna2000 Added an image to illustrate the query is valid.  I

Comment: @axna2000 Do you have a max number or do you need use dynamic sql.  If dynamic, then I need to know which database you are connected to.

Comment: @axna2000 extended the query.  I'm sure you can see the pattern

Comment: @axna2000 I can't supply a dynamic pivot without knowing what database you are connected to.

Comment: sorry jhon, i think this missed persepsion, i mean transport 1 is as field and transport 2 as field to no more transport 3 etc